# How does silentRenew and and useRefreshToken work in Angular auth oidc?

Tags: openid-connect, angular-auth-oidc-client

The project I am currently working on has this configuration:

```
auth: {
 silentRenew: true,
 maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: 700,
 useRefreshToken: true,
 renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 60,
}
```

I think by setting silentRenew and useRefreshToken to true, it would automatically extend the session.
But how do they actually work behind the scene? 
I am currently trying to implement a function where a modal will pop up when the session time is 5 mins left.

How I was observing my session expire time:

1. After the user got the token, I call a check token method:
2. In the check token method, I basically just console.log the current time and expired time

```
    this.oidcSecurityService.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(() => {
                    this.token = this.oidcSecurityService.getToken();
                    this.checkTokenExpired(this.token);
                });
```

```
    checkTokenExpired( tokenId: String) {
        setInterval( () => {
            const currentTime = (new Date).getTime();
            const expireSessionTime = (JSON.parse(atob(tokenId.split('.')[1]))).exp * 1000;
            const exp= new Date(expireSessionTime);
            const cur = new Date(currentTime);
            console.log('cur', cur);
            console.log('exp', exp);
        }, 10000);
    }
```

However, after the session time expired, the session is still working and user can still interact with the App. 
So I assume that the `silentRenew` and `useRefresh` token renew the session behind the scene.
But when did it renew the session and how can I catch that so I can get the renewed session expire time?

Comment: So what the lib does is checking periodically if your token is about to expire and then renewing it. Either with an iFrame, which should not be used anymore, because browser block this, or with a refresh token. This happens behind the scenes, the lib is talking to your refresh endpoint and exchanges the tokens. There are several public events you can register to: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/main/projects/angular-auth-oidc-client/src/lib/public-events/event-types.ts